# How to find a specific id by clicking on a button anywhere on a page in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a specific id by clicking on a button that can be anywhere on the page.

I am trying as follows:

```
$(document).on('click','.cia_delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let thisBtn = $(this);
    let refreshArea = thisBtn.closest("body").find("#cia_refresh_area");
});
```

In the above code, I want to find `#cia_refresh_area` that can be anywhere in the document.

Is the above code correct?

Comment: This would work but is way to expensive. Just use: `let refreshArea = $("#cia_refresh_area");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the feedbacks of your question, your code should be like this:

```
$(".cia_delete").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    let refreshArea = $("#cia_refresh_area");
});
```

Anyways, I suggest you to read more about the [JQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Like a basic example related to the code:

- **$(".cia_delete")** will match against (and will selects) all elements that have the class **.cia_delete**
- **$("#cia_refresh_area")** will match against (and will selects) the element with  ID attribute equal to **cia_refresh_area**